# Variable dimension dynamic array in C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, tensor

I would like to implement a STL-like tensor template in C++, which needs overload operator[] to access its elements, which may looks like this:

```
Tensor<double,2> tensor2
{
    {1,2,3},
    {4,5,6}
};
std::cout<< tensor2[1][2]<<'\n';
```

For low dimensions, it may be easy to use some thing like

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>>
```

But this would not be easy to use for higher dimensions.
Also I would like to implement product between tensors and contraction between dimensions in one tensor.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain what's wrong with nested vectors?

Comment: Implement a multidimensional vector type if the nesting is too illegible/inflexible.

Comment: There is no such thing, but you can use plain 1d array with complex indexing like `std::size_t plain_index(std::size_t i, std::size_t j, std::size_t k, ...)`

Comment: There is no trivial solution.  You can refer to implementation of `shape` class and `IndexUtil::MultidimensionalIndexToLinearIndex` function from Tensorflow source code on github.

Comment: I would suggest a library for this.  Either `Boost`, `Eigen` or `Tensorflow`.  Don't reinvent the wheel unless there is some functionality or performance target these can't do.

Comment: I realized Boost has a better solution when I try to implement this concept. Thus I implemented just some basic operations to practice template programming and then turn to Boost.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the multi-dimensional array with some very basic operations. Since Boost.MultiArray offers a far better solution, my implementation is just for demonstration.

```
namespace DataStructures
{
    struct ExtentList   //Discribe extents of dimensions for MultiArray
    {
        std::vector<size_t> dimensions;
        ExtentList() = default;
        template<typename Iterator, typename SFINAE = std::enable_if_t<std::_Is_iterator_v<Iterator>>>
        ExtentList(Iterator begin, Iterator end) : dimensions(begin, end) {}
        //operator[] used to initialize the extents
        ExtentList& operator[](size_t n) { dimensions.push_back(n); return *this; }
        ExtentList after_front() const { return ExtentList(++dimensions.cbegin(), dimensions.cend()); }
        //at() used to access extents
        size_t at(size_t n) const { return dimensions.at(n); }
    };

    static ExtentList Extents;

    template<
        typename ElemType,                                                  //Underlying Type
        size_t Dimension,                                                   //Dimension of MultiArray
        typename ElementAllocator = std::allocator<ElemType>,               //Allocator for elements
        template<typename, typename> typename ContainerType = std::vector,  //Underlying container type
        template<typename> typename ContainerAllocator = std::allocator>    //Allocator for container
    class MultiArray
    {
        //Necessary for contructor with ExtentList
        friend class MultiArray<ElemType, Dimension + 1U, ElementAllocator, ContainerType, ContainerAllocator>;

        using value_type = typename
            std::conditional_t<
            Dimension == 1U, 
            ElemType,
            MultiArray<ElemType, Dimension - 1U, ElementAllocator, ContainerType, ContainerAllocator>>;
        using allocator_type = typename
            std::conditional_t<
            Dimension == 1U,
            ElementAllocator,
            ContainerAllocator<value_type>>;
        ContainerType<value_type, allocator_type> data;


    public:
        MultiArray() = default;
        MultiArray(size_t n, const value_type& val) : data(n, val) {}

        template<typename SFINAE = std::enable_if_t<(Dimension == 1U)>>
            MultiArray(ExtentList extents, const ElemType& elem) : data(extents.at(0), elem) {}
        template<typename SFINAE = std::enable_if_t<(Dimension >= 2U)>, typename SFINAE2 = SFINAE>
            MultiArray(ExtentList extents, const ElemType& elem) : data(extents.at(0), value_type(extents.after_front(), elem)) {}

        MultiArray(std::initializer_list<value_type> ilist) : data(ilist) {}


        template<typename ... SizeType>
        MultiArray(size_t N, SizeType... args) : data(N, value_type(args...)) {}

        value_type& operator[](size_t n) { return data[n]; }
        void push_back(const value_type& elem) { data.push_back(elem); }
    };
}
```

The idea is to implement the multi-dimensional array with recursive template, so subscription and list initialization operations are allowed.

```
namespace DS = DataStructures;

DS::MultiArray<int, 2> matrix_2d
{
    { 1,2,3 },
    { 4,5,6 },
    { 7,8,9 }
};
for (size_t i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
    for (size_t j = 0; j != 3; ++j)
        std::cout << matrix_2d[i][j] << ' ';

DS::MultiArray<int, 3> matrix_3d(DS::Extents[10][10][10], 0);
size_t sum = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i != DS::Extents.at(0); ++i)
    for (size_t j = 0; j != DS::Extents.at(1); ++j)
        for (size_t k = 0; k != DS::Extents.at(2); ++k)
            sum += (matrix_3d[i][j][k] = i * 100 + j * 10 + k);
std::cout << sum << '\n' << matrix_3d[9][9][9] << '\n';
```

The idea of ExtentList comes from Boost. It is better than variable function parameter list or variable template.